# Matching characters including line breaks and return carriages

Tags: php, regex

I have this specific line of text and clients submit, and the line automatically breaks at 65 characters and i need to modify my regular expression to look for one more additional line, return carriages or new line characters **up until the first punctuation mark** such as .,!,?

An example of the line being matched.:

```
Snippet: It's time again for the Annual State Marching Event, This Saturday at 5pm.
```

The above line exceeds 65 characters, and sometimes the lines are broken like this

```
Snippet: It's time again for the Annual State Marching Event, This 
Saturday at 5pm.
```

Which appears as `Event, This\r\n`
This is the regexp i use:

```
preg_match('/Snippet:(\s)?+(.*)\./i', $html_part, $matches) ? $matches[2] : '';
```

I've tried on my won to escape the punctuation marks, but no luck. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `s` modifier, like so:

```
/Snippet:(\s)?+(.*)\./is
```

> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.
>   This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class
>   such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the
>   setting of this modifier.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

[Demo](http://regexr.com?30rh5)

Comment: But I have these lines amongst some other text in a paragraph, which is why i only want it to stop at a punctuation mark. The s modifier ends up capturing the other data beyond the what i need to be.

Comment: Try making the capturing group non-greedy: `(.*?)`

Comment: Using this `/Snippet:(\s)?+(.*)\./Uis` worked but how do i still keep the punctuation mark, so it appears as a full sentence?

Comment: The only punctuation mark you have in your regex is the period, and it's not being included because it is not in your capturing group. Remove the `\.`, that should at least help, if not fix it. You should also look into the `$` symbol, which matches the "end of the subject string" (see the `D` modifier).

Comment: I know but that would kinda defeat the purpose :/ is there anyway to add the character to match up to (in this case the punctuation mark) to the capturing group? Because i removed the `\.` and nothing happened, my group wasn't even captured.

Comment: Nevermind, I just made the punctuation marks another possible group and append it to the first second capturing group `/Snippet:(\s)?+(.*)(\.|\!|\?)/Uis` Thanks for help!